# Regarding Vcom on LPC1769

Tags: arm, microcontroller

I am using the ARM-based microcontroller LPC1769 and the LPCXpresso IDE. I am using an example project for Vcom using USB Device controller in 1769. By default it works at 9600 baud. But I don't understand how to change the baud rate - I want to use it at higher baud rate.

Comment: What makes you believe that it won't work at higher baud rate?

Answer (score 0):

Please define every thing well for better answer, I am providing the computer side answer,

If you are connection with Computer, Its using generic Com port which will be assigned to the device,

now, again if you are using computer, the com port have configuration. go to device manager, and see properties>> Configuration>> there you will see baud rate.

go and change that,

that will do. :)

Edit: Updated with links of support in Driver Side,

I have few link for the same VCP(Virtual Comp Port) Drivers you can use

```
http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm
```

and Documentation for the same in different different case, please refer documentation first :)

```
http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets.htm
```

this is all from my side :)

Comment: Thank You...
But the thing is I have that USB inbuilt in UC itself and I want to change baudrate there only. I know hoe to do it over PC....

Comment: I am not much in micro controller, I am on software side, So I have updated the answer please refer.. answer updated.. :)